# Total open connections reached the connection limit

Tags: unity-game-engine, flask, get-request, waitress

I'm running Python Flask with Waitress. I'm starting the server using the following code:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, request
from waitress import serve

@app.route("/get")
def first_method():
   ...

@app.route("/second")
def second_method():
   ...

app = Flask(__name__)
app.static_folder = 'static'
serve(app, host="ip_address", port=8080)
```

I'm calling the server from a Webpage and also from Unity. From the webpage, I'm using the following example get request in jQuery:

```
$.get("/get", { variable1: data1, variable2: data2 }).done(function (data) {
...
}
```

In Unity I'm using the following call:

```
http://ip_address/get?msg=data1?data2
```

Unfortuantely, after some time I'm getting the error on the server `total open connections reached the connection limit, no longer accepting new connections`. This especially happens with Unity. I assume that for each get request a new channel/connection is established.

How can this be fixed, i.e. how can channels/connections be reused?

Comment: I am getting the same error right now. Have you found any solution?

Comment: I am also getting this error and also asking if anyone has recently found a solution?